# Gcloud kubernetes certificate generated too early

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I've been following the gcloud kubernetes tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app#cloud-shell_1).

I was able to follow all the steps up to "Creating a GKE cluster". I set my zone to `australia-southeast-1a`. Then I created the cluster and got the following success messages:

[image]

However, when I try to inspect the cluster with `kubectl get nodes` or deploy an app, I get the following error message:

> error: failed to create deployment: Post
> "https://35.189.27.151/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments?fieldManager=kubectl-create":
> x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time
> 2021-05-31T19:28:36+10:00 is before 2021-05-31T23:17:39Z

This seems to indicate that the server thinks the current time is in `US-EAST`, but that the certificate was generated using Greenwich mean time. I can't figure out why that would be happening, so throwing this out to more experienced kubernetes/gcloud developers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is correct and that your host's time is incorrect.

The current time is: 2021-06-01T02:25:25Z (GMT)

And in Sydney: 2021-06-01T12:25:25+10:00

**Note** Sydney is +10 from GMT

Your server was before GMT; same date and earlier hour

Answer (score 0):

The timezone mismatch is [due to the fact that](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits#using_container-optimized_os):

> Container-Optimized OS is the default node OS Image in Kubernetes
> Engine and other Kubernetes deployments on Google Cloud Platform.

[and because of that](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#changing_the_time_zone):

> The default time zone of Container-Optimized OS is UTC0.
>
> Note that `/etc` is stateless, so the timezone will be reset to the
> default (UTC0) every reboot.

In order to fix that you can create a symbolic link to your desired time zone as in the following example:

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific /etc/localtime
```

Setting you GKE cluster to the correct time will fix your issue.